# Uploading file, how validate the kind of file fom django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to upload videos from django admin, but I can't see how to validate that the user is upload only video files, and no other file types.

Any idea?

Thanks

Sorry with my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is to create a custom ModelForm for your admin class, and write a `clean_[video_field_name]` method that validates the file and throws a ValidationError if it's not of the correct type.

The docs for doing this are here: [Adding custom validation to the admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin)